# Something is wrong with this user's suspension

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, per-site-meta, account-suspension

[This user](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16042/badps-sockpuppet) is currently suspended on meta. There is however *no* hint of this on his user page except for the fact he has 1 reputation on meta and 21 on the main site. I picked a custom ban reason for this.

He also does not appear on [the list of people currently suspended.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/users)

Another user has received a not-for-science suspension on the same site, and his profile works correctly however. (I'm not putting a direct link here to protect the guilty.)

They've both been suspended for a custom reason on the same site, so I'm kind of at a loss here as to what might've happened.

Comment: It's about time that sock puppet got suspended! :D

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'm afraid those are just throwaway accounts of a darker, larger mysterious machination, but I really have no idea as to who'd be behind all this. Probably rchern, however. Look at what happened last time she was trusted with a password.

Comment: Uhhh... now he's not even suspended anymore.

Comment: I smell a **conspiracy** to make you ask a question that will ultimately be closed as _too localized_. Glad to see it worked :)

Comment: Investigating; I assume it relates to child-metas and the odd duality of the account between 2 sites...

Comment: Interesting. I posted a [now-deleted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112818/131713) to the now-deleted "New User page - LIVE " post about a suspension banner not showing up. However, when I went back to look, that user was no longer suspended, so I don't know if this is the same issue.

Comment: @PopularDemand I expect that was more "the dev forgot to put that banner on the page"

Comment: I doubt it, @MarcGravell; one of the commenters pointed out that the banner was working for a different suspended user at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, it looks like it should not have been possible to suspend the user on the child-meta, since **forever**, the suspension data has been "owned" by the parent site (i.e. gaming.SE) and will get overwritten regularly.

Consequently, I will be making the "contact/suspend user" functionality relate to the main Q&A site, to reflect how it has always operated.

Comment: That's not the case as you can see on the other meta suspension. It's been issued for a few hours now and still holds tight.

Comment: @badp honestly, it is. I haz teh codez. The question is: **when does it update from the parent site** ;p I'll sync it, and I entirely expect it to disappear... gimme 2 minutes...

Comment: @badp and "boom", gone. I **DID NOT** "unsuspend" them; I simply simulated the "sync user" that happens routinely when the user is active on meta

Comment: blech. Now I'd have to suspend him on the main site? :|

Comment: @badp the thing is, I've checked back 18 months, and this has always actually been the case

Comment: You should have given yourself the winning lottery numbers when you went 18 months ago

Comment: @Juan I did, but that meant that I decided to reduce my hours by a few, which meant that this question was answered by Nick, which meant that I didn't have a need to go back 18 months - and at that point it just got so confusing that I didn't know **what** was happening. To cut a long story short, I'm now my own great-great-great-grandfather.

Comment: "Well, now everything is back as it was, and if history doesn't care that our degenerate friend Marc Gravell is his own grandfather, then who are we to judge?"